Search filter inside of an angular drop down
Need assistance in implementing a search box into an angular drop down and I don't know how to quite get it to function correctly based on what code I have so far for the html and typescript.
Can anybody please help me to implement a search filter with the select component in my application?
I'm using a search component that can be inserted into other components using a selector in the typescript called 'lf-material-search'.
Here is the HTML for the search component
<ng-template #legacyInput>
<form class="input-group add-border"
  [formGroup]="form"
  [class.btn-search-input]="hasButtonStyles"
  [class.flex-nowrap]="hasButtonStyles"
  [class.search-input-loading]="isLoading"
  [class.search-input-focused]="hasFocus()">
<span *ngIf="hasGroupAddon"
  class="input-group-addon">
<img src="/assets/images/payhoa/other/search.svg"/>
</span>
<span *ngIf="!hasGroupAddon"
      class="search-input-container">
<span *ngIf="isLoading"
      class="d-inline-flex p-relative p-0 loading"></span>
</span>
<input #searchInput
       formControlName="search"
       class="form-control"
       type="text"
       aria-label="Material search input"
       [placeholder]="defaultPlaceholder"/>
<span *ngIf="hasGroupAddon"
      class="input-group-addon"
      (click)="clearSearch()">
 <img src="/assets/images/app/icons/icon_close.svg"/>
 </span>
 </form>
</ng-template>

 <ng-container *ngIf="newInput; else legacyInput">
  <ng-container [formGroup]="form">
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline"
                class="payhoa-field payhoa-search w-100">
    <mat-icon matPrefix>search</mat-icon>
    <input matInput
           type="text"
           aria-label="Search and find results"
           [formControlName]="'search'"
           [placeholder]="defaultPlaceholder">
    </mat-form-field>
   </ng-container>
  </ng-container>

This is where I added the selector from the search component into the dropdown that is in another component.
<ul *ngIf="options" class="dropdown-menu" style="width: 100%;">
  <!--                *<lf-material-search #searchInput 
  (updated)="toggleAccount($event)"></lf-material-search>-->
        <lf-material-search #searchInput 
  (updated)="toggleAccount(1,  false)"></lf-material-search>*
      
        <ng-container *ngIf="options.assets && 
  options.assets.length">
            <li class="dropdown-item group-header">
                Assets
            </li>
            <ng-template [ngForOf]="options.assets" let-asset 
  ngFor>
                <li (click)="this.toggleAccount(asset)" 
    [class.selected]="selection.isSelected(asset)"
                    class="dropdown-item">
                    <a>{{asset.display}}</a>
                </li>
            </ng-template>
        </ng-container>

   </ul>

but I still can't get any results when I do a search in the application. What am I missing or need to pass from the typescript below to the lf-material-search to get this to work?
Typescript
@UntilDestroy()
@Component({
 selector: 'report-filter-account-register-selector',
 templateUrl: './account-register-selector.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./account-register-selector.component.scss'],
 })

 export class AccountRegisterSelectorComponent implements OnInit
{
 jwt: JwtLegFiClaims;

  expanded: boolean = false;

@Input()
public container: FilterContainerComponent;

public selection: SelectionModel<AccountRegisterFilterOption> = new 
   SelectionModel<AccountRegisterFilterOption>(true);

public options: AccountRegisterFilters = null;

constructor(
    private _reportsService: ReportsService,
    private _growler: GrowlerService,
   ) {
  }

ngOnInit() {
  this.container.register(this);
  this.jwt = LegFiJwtService.read();  



 this._reportsService.getAccountRegisterFilters()
     .pipe(untilDestroyed(this)).subscribe(
        (options) => {
            this.options = options;
            this.container.notifyReady(this);
        },
        () => {
            this._growler.error(
                    
            );
         },
   );
}

toggleAccount(account, children = false) {
 this.selection.toggle(account);
 if (children) {
    const doToggleOn = 
  !this.selection.isSelected(account.children[0]);
    account.children.forEach((child) => {
        if (doToggleOn) {
            this.selection.select(child);
        } else {
            this.selection.deselect(child);
        }
    });
  }
 }
}

When I type in the word 'Burnt' it doesn't filter for that nor anything else

If anyone could help me I would definitely appreciate it.

In general implement a search when depend of a formControl you have an observable that is the control.valueChange transform (using switchMap or map)
Then you use pipeAsync to get the list
<input [formControl]="control">
<ul>
  @for(value of list$|async;track $index)
  {
  <li>{{value}}</li>
  }
</ul>

If you have, e.g. a
export const List = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six'];

You use
  list$: Observable<string[]> = this.control.valueChanges.pipe(
    startWith(''),
    map((value: any) => {
      if (!value) return List;
      value = value.toUpperCase();
      return List.filter((x: string) => x.toUpperCase().indexOf(value) >= 0)
    })
  );

If you call to an API when change the value you use switchMap
  list$: Observable<string[]> = this.control.valueChanges.pipe(
    startWith(''),
    debounceTime(100),   //<--this is to not call to api so many times
    switchMap((value: any) => {
      if (!value) return this.dataService.getAll();
      return this.dataService.getAllContains(value)
    })
  );

In the stackblitz I use rxjs operator of in the service, generally it's used one kind of this.httpClient.get(...)
